error bean serialize in schedul job with redissonClient and SpringBoot
I use org.redisson:redisson(3.39.0) and springboot spring.boot(3.0.0)
my redis is cluster and i create a scheduler like this :
    Config config = new Config();
    config.useClusterServers().addNodeAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:1001");
    config.useClusterServers().setPassword("redisHostPassword");
    RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
    CustomizableThreadFactory threadFactory = new CustomizableThreadFactory("myScheduler2");
    threadFactory.setDaemon(true);

    ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor =
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                    2,
                    2,
                    1L,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    new LinkedBlockingQueue(),
                    threadFactory);

    WorkerOptions workerOptions =
            WorkerOptions.defaults()
                    .workers(6)
                    .taskTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .executorService(threadPoolExecutor);

    RScheduledExecutorService executorService =
            redisson.getExecutorService("myScheduler2");
    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.delete();
    executorService.registerWorkers(workerOptions);

    RedisJobDetail redisJobDetail = new RedisJobDetail();
    redisJobDetail.setJobClass(MyScheduledTaskChild.class);
    String name ="MyScheduledTask2";
    Map<String, String> cfg = new HashMap<>();
    cfg.put("jobName", name);
    redisJobDetail.setJobDataMap(cfg);
    MyScheduledTask myScheduledTask = (MyScheduledTask) 
    context.getBean(redisJobDetail.getJobClass());
    myScheduledTask.setTaskName("MyScheduledTask2");

    myScheduledTask.setJobDetail(redisJobDetail);
    myScheduledTask.initJob();

    executorService.scheduleAsync(myScheduledTask, CronSchedule.of("0 47/1 * ? * * *"));

and my MyScheduledTask job has a bean that must be have and class is :
  @Component
  public abstract class MyScheduledTask implements Runnable {
  String taskName;

  JobService jobService;
  private RedisJobDetail jobDetail;

  public void setJobDetail(RedisJobDetail jobDetail) {
      this.jobDetail = jobDetail;
  }

  @Autowired
  public void setJobService(JobService jobService) {
       this.jobService = jobService;
  }

  public abstract void initJob() ;

  @Override
  public void run() {
     jobService.printttt();
  }

  protected abstract void doLogic(Map<String, String> param) throws Exception;

  public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
      this.taskName = taskName;
  }
 }

When I run my program, I see an error that redisson can't serialize the bean, and I even change the codec, but this problem is not solved.
and this is my stack trace :
2024-12-17T11:46:53.446+03:30  WARN 15476 --- [scheduleRedis] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobWorker': Invocation of init method failed
2024-12-17T11:47:03.660+03:30  INFO 15476 --- [scheduleRedis] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-12-17T11:47:03.701+03:30  INFO 15476 --- [scheduleRedis] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-12-17T11:47:03.718+03:30 ERROR 15476 --- [scheduleRedis] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobWorker': Invocation of init method failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:222) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:336) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:288) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.instantiateSingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1122) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1093) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1030) ~[spring-beans-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:987) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:627) ~[spring-context-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1361) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1350) ~[spring-boot-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
    at com.redisTaskScheduler.scheduleRedis.ScheduleRedisApplication.main(ScheduleRedisApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: A StackOverflow occurred. The most likely cause is that your data has a circular reference resulting in infinite recursion. Try enabling references with Kryo.setReferences(true). If your data structure is really more than 1308 levels deep then try increasing your Java stack size.
Serialization trace:
boundOperations (org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate)
template (org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultClusterOperations)
clusterOps (org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate)
template (org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultClusterOperations)
clusterOps (org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate)
template (org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultClusterOperations)
....
jobService (com.redisTaskScheduler.scheduleRedis.MyScheduledTaskChild)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ReflectField.write(ReflectField.java:99) ~[kryo-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:109) ~[kryo-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:642) ~[kryo-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ReflectField.write(ReflectField.java:71) ~[kryo-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:109) ~[kryo-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:642) ~[kryo-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ReflectField.write(ReflectField.java:71) ~[kryo-5.6.2.jar:na]
....


Add the stacktrace you get.

hi deinum, i added that

Apparently your job has a circular reference (that is what the error is telling you). I also don't really get the setup, why not just an @Scheduled? Your RScheduledExecutorService is also weird you create it and then shut it down? Finally you shouldn't be doing this in an @PostConstruct method but rather in an ApplicationRunner / CommandLineRunner which will run after all beans have been setup.

I use corn pattren beacause i must read it from database, and i shutdown it beacause i want deschedule previous schedule, and i change @PostConstruct to CommandLineRunner but the error is same, thanks Deinum
